# SolrCloud SQL support

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

Does anybody know whether the entire [Apache Calcite SQL dialect](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html) is supported by **SolrCloud**?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not support all the operations available in the SQL dialect, as they're not easily implemented or in some cases, maybe not possible in an effective manner in a document search engine context (i.e. Solr has no current support for anything similar to `UPDATE collection SET foo = bar WHERE field = 'baz'`).

For reference you can see how Solr [handles different keywords and syntax in the Solr SQL syntax page in the reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/parallel-sql-interface.html#solr-sql-syntax).

Among other limitations, one is that Solr's JDBC interface is currently not handling other types than string very well.

Comment: Thank you indeed. Even though the SQL support is limitated for now as you mention, the foundation really encourage to work with. I hope the path with Calcite really goes into a wider support of the SQL standard (operators, functions, spatial). SQL and Lucene have their own niches in the industry. Putting Lucene and SQL together, even partially, I think it's a great break-trough for Apache SolrCloud.